# Django query using OR condition

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django, how do you query to get two different values, like in the following?

```
profile_setting = (pSetting.objects.get(module="my_mod", setting_value=1) or
                   pSetting.objects.get(module="my_mod", setting_value=0))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checkout django's [`Q`-class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
profile_setting = pSetting.objects.get(Q(module="my_mod"),\
                  Q(setting_value=1)|Q(setting_value=0))
```

Furthermore to improve your coding style, have a look at some [coding guidelines](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/?from=olddocs#model-style), you should better name your model class `PSetting`.

Comment: I agree about the style - also look at Python's PEP8 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for style guide.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you are grabbing only one object?

If you are trying to grab a queryset of a bunch of objects, all you need to do is chain filters together:

```
profile_setting = pSetting.objects.filter(module="my_mod", setting_value__in=0)
                         .filter(module="my_mod", setting_value__in=1)
```

However, since everything but setting_value is the same, you can simply look for a list or tuple:

```
profile_setting = pSetting.objects.filter(module="my_mod", setting_value__in=[0,1])
```

(alexdb's suggestion above is fine if and only if you are sure that you'll be getting only one object as a response to your query)

Answer (score 3):

There is a `Q()` object for this task - look here: [Complex Queries with Q() object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

In example:

```
profile_setting = pSetting.objects.get(
    Q(module="my_mod", setting_value=1) | Q(module="my_mod", setting_value=0)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 profile_setting = pSetting.objects.get(module="my_mod",setting_value__in=[0,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of query check this documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

and for your specific problem you can pass multiple queryset objects(Q)
for queryset use | for OR condition and & for AND condition in both get() and filter() functions.